# Тэг script не работает в JSX-React, только в html

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Есть виджет рейтинга tophotels, нужно отобразить его в react-компоненте на странице, JSX ругается на него, при использовании пакета (react-helmet), так же ничего не происходит. В html-структуре страницы скрипт есть, но визуально его нет

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://tophotels.ru/js/app-inform.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
            (function() {
                try { tophotels.inform.init('AZBYFHV').load(); 
                }catch(e) {}
             })();
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

Comment: он закомментирован /*

Comment: скрипт был изначально таким, и в режиме разработки при перерендеринге страницы виджет отображается, но он становится единственным элементом на ней

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена с помощью библиотеки:
"https://www.npmjs.com/package/dangerously-set-html-content"

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.